# How do i force a link to open in the native browser of a mobile os?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, instagram

I am trying to recreate the behavior of the service https://allmylinks.com/. I need a working solution for iOs and Android. I want to place a link in my bio for my customers for my other social media accounts. This Link should (force) open in the native/standard mobile browser, e.g. safari for ios.

I tried to work around this problem by faking a pdf download, which was suggested in some older posts. This didn't work. I further tried to use URI scehemes, depending on the os used. Didn't work either